# Does polymorphism apply on value objects?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Consider a scenario when a parent class only has attributes and "no method" and several child classes are extending the parent class for code re-usability.

These objects are essentially value objects and if a child value object is passed in a method accepting the parent variable as input, will you still call it a polymorphic behavior when child has no behavior to override? For example:

```
class Parent { int value = 100; /* doesn't have any method to be overriden */ }

class Child1 extends Parent {};

class Child2 extends Parent {};

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent obj1 = new Child1();
        doSomething(obj1);

        Parent obj2 = new Child2();
        doSomething(obj2);

        Child1 obj3 = new Child1();
        doSomething(obj3);

        Child2 obj4 = new Child2();
        doSomething(obj4);
    }

    static void doSomething(Parent p) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Will you still call above a polymorphic behavior even though there is no behavior at all?

Comment: What do you mean by attributes? Member variables? If so, no, member variables are not polymorphic.

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest but there is no one to here it, does it still make a sound? I would say it does.

Comment: Some example code would make it much easier to understand your question.

Comment: @Andy Turner Yes, i mean member variables. Still not polymorphic even if `method(Parent p)` is passed a child object?

Comment: @B.Ali easiest thing to do is to try it.

Comment: Just for your information: [Java Tutorials Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: @MockerTim thanks for sharing the link but please share your knowledge instead in case you know the difference between the question asked and the material mentioned in the link. Thanks

Comment: @B.Ali If I had time to answer, I would add an answer. As far as you insist, here is another portion of the information, that may help your to find an answer to your question yourself: [Java - Polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).

Comment: @MockerTim the moment i read "the Deer class is considered to be polymorphic since this has multiple inheritance" i stopped reading further.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class A { int foobar = 42; }
class B extends A {}

public class Test3 {
    public static void printAsFoobarValue(A a) { System.out.println(a.foobar); }
    public static void printBsFoobarValue(B b) { System.out.println(b.foobar); }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A c = new B();
        printAsFoobarValue(a);
        printAsFoobarValue(b);
        printAsFoobarValue(c);
        printBsFoobarValue(b);
    }
}
```

I'll call this polymorph.

Comment: I'll go with that "In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types". Same interface, different types. In programming language theory we should understand directly accessing members through `.` as an interface not to be confused with the narrower Java construct `interface`.

Comment: This is the example [B.Ali](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5761052/b-ali) should have started with.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Parent`class in your post does not have methods to be overriden by subclasses then `dosomething` method in Test does something which does not invoke any overriden methods - if this is the case then it is not polymorphism